# Should I use save or update to update one or more elements of an embedded document in Mongodb using Morphia

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, morphia

### **TL;DR**

Using Morphia ORM, Should I use save(entity/doc) every time the elements (more than one element) of the list (subdocument) changes or use update with update-operations to only update the changed elements?

### **Background/Scenario**

I have the following **document** (Exam) with the **qa** (QuestionAnswer) subdocument (that can grow between **50-100** entries). Taking into account the following:

1. Around 80% of the operations are **update** more than one entries of the **qa** subdocument at a time
2. A record (Exam) is specific to a **User** hence no concurrent updates
3. A screen displays 5-10 questions, when user moves to next/prev page, those questions on current screen will be posted to server to be updated
4. QuestionsAnswer is specific to Exam record

document (just to give an idea)

```
{
    "user": "user-record-ref",
    "name": "some-name", 
    "dob": "some-timestamp", 
    "qa": [
        {
            "question": "some-question1", 
            "choices": ["A", "B"],
            "answer": ["A"]
            ...
        },
        {
            "question": "some-question2", 
            "choices": [],
            "answer": ["descriptive-answer"]
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I have modelled the above using Spring Boot & Morphia in the following manner (just to give an idea)

```
public class Exam {
   private String name; 
   private Date dob;
   @Reference
   private User user;  
   @Embedded
   List<QuestionAnswer> qa;  
}
```

### **Questions**

Using **Morphia ORM**, Should I use **save(entity/doc)** every time the elements of the list (subdocument) changes or use **update with update-operations** to only update the changed elements?

- If I were to use **save**, taking into account **80% freq. (mentioned above)** is it efficient to keep re-saving the entire entity this often?
- If I were to use **update** is it efficient to do **x** number of update calls where x is number of questions (elements of subdoc) requested to be updated (each question with diff. id hence, diff. query clause)?
- Which is most performant?
- Since **qa** subdocument will be updated quite often and is specific to the document (not shared) how else can I model this to make updating the elements of **subodcument** painless, efficient and scalable while exercising good practice?

Answer (score 0):

I see the **save** method as being one of simplicity for coding. It will always be more efficient to send **update** calls to the backend since it reduces the among of traffic going over the wire and reduces the amount of data changing on disk. If you trust your database, you can also set your write concern to not even wait for the save - maybe the application response very fast.

However, since you're doing so many changes to this particular QA subdocument, I would consider saving the QA in its own collection. This was you can call **save** on the QA object itself and not have to worry about sending the rest of the User data over to the server on every call.